# Create "ravelled" face image sklearn.datasets.fetch_lfw_people

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

I was trying to create an lfw dataset. the things i need for my code are the ravelled images like in the documetation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_lfw_people.html

> data: numpy array of shape (13233, 2914)
> Each row corresponds to a ravelled face image of original size 62 x 47 pixels. Changing the slice_ or resize parameters will change the shape of the output.

How do i actually create the "ravelled" images.

When i was looking at their source code
they seems to do sth like this: (faces are the return "data" in the fetch_lfw_people)

`faces = np.zeros((n_faces, h, w), dtype=np.float32)`

```
person_names, file_paths = [], []
    for person_name in sorted(listdir(data_folder_path)):
        folder_path = join(data_folder_path, person_name)
        if not isdir(folder_path):
            continue
        paths = [join(folder_path, f) for f in sorted(listdir(folder_path))]
        n_pictures = len(paths)
        if n_pictures >= min_faces_per_person:
            person_name = person_name.replace("_", " ")
            person_names.extend([person_name] * n_pictures)
            file_paths.extend(paths)
```

I do not really understand how they create the "paths"
or if there a better way to do it lmk. tks